find out the order tracking details in mysql
I have 3 tables as follows:

order - This table contains order information, with order_id as the primary key:

order_id   order_status_id  amount
1001       18               1500


order_products - This table contains information about the products in each order:

order_product_id  order_id  model  name  amount
1                 1001      m1     n1    1000
2                 1001      m2     n2    500


order_tracking - This table contains all the tracking details of orders. It includes multiple rows per product with various tracking updates. I want to fetch only the latest tracking status:

id  order_product_id  tracking_id  delivery_partner  item_status  time
1   1                t001          ekart             processing   t1
2   1                t001          eKart             Processed    t2
3   2                t001          ekart             processing   t1
4   1                t001          eKart             Shipped      t3

Please help me find the best way to retrieve the latest item status along with all the product details
I have been trying to fetch data using a join, but I did not get the correct result. I am getting multiple records for a single product, but I want to fetch only the latest tracking details.

Show us the query you have along with it's result, and what the expected result is.  select order_product_id, max(id) from order_tracking group by 1 is probably very relevant.

Use a window function similar to the one in the duplicate, or consult the doc. btw, it's spelled "delivery" not "delhivery"

@AllanWind I want to fetch tracking details as well as product details from order_product table

You want to revise the question with additional data not respond with a comment.  Your question has been closed.  Review the duplicate issue, it's very relevant, and if you need more help open a new question.
